# GHC: Display of unicode characters

Tags: haskell, unicode, ghc

Further  to my first question on the management of the unicode characters in the production of .exe file, this is also a bug in GHC?

```
> print "Frère"
"Fr\233re"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`print x` is equivalent to `putStrLn (show x)`, where `show` converts a type of the `Show` class to a string representation.

In your case, x already has the `String` type. One might think that the String implementation of `show` would simply return its argument unchanged, but actually it transforms it into an ASCII string literal token with the same syntax as used in Haskell source code. This is done by surrounding it with quotes and by escaping 'special' characters (basically whatever is not on your keyboard).

So, this is not a bug but rather the expected behavior of `print`. If you want to output your string directly, use `putStrLn` instead.

Comment: I just got bitten by this. I guess for legacy reasons `show` does what it does, but it's certainly not helpful in the REPL when a Unicode string doesn't show as you expect!

Comment: is there an alternative to `show` that handles unicode without transforming it into ASCII?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
> putStrLn "Frère"
Frère
```

Comment: If you are on Windows, you may get "Frère", but you may also get "*** Exception: <stdout>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)" depending on the character, your codepage (yes, codepage) and probably the phase of the moon. Really annoys me.

Comment: @n.m. That's why nearly all my Haskell programs intended to run on Windows start out with something involving `mkTextEncoding` and `"//TRANSLIT"`

Comment: @JeremyList //TRANSLIT is really **really** annoying. GHCi is perfectly capable of displaying every Unicode character in the console; why must my program jump through hoops in order to not bloody crash upon encountering so much as an accented letter? Could it be just linked by default with the same libraries GHCi is using?

Comment: Yeah, it is actually a bug (scheduled to be fixed in GHC 7.12.1). GHCi prevents the issue by catching the exception, not by using different libraries.