# Using scandinavian letters Å Ä Ö in a haskell program

Tags: haskell, symbols, letters

I'm writing a Haskell program as an assignment for school. It's a datingprogram in english that in the end leads to a "chat" with your perfect match. I want the chat to be able to switch and write in swedish, wich means the program needs a code for the letters å ä ö. How do I do that?

```
import Data.Char 

kons = "qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnmQWRTPSDFGHJKLZXCVNM" 
veral = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

gemen:: Char -> Char
gemen 'A' = 'a'
gemen 'B' = 'b'
gemen 'C' = 'c'
gemen 'D' = 'd'
gemen 'E' = 'e'
gemen 'F' = 'f'
gemen 'G' = 'g'
gemen 'H' = 'h'
gemen 'I' = 'i'
gemen 'J' = 'j'
gemen 'K' = 'k'
gemen 'L' = 'l'
gemen 'M' = 'm'
gemen 'N' = 'n'
gemen 'O' = 'o'
gemen 'P' = 'p'
gemen 'Q' = 'q'
gemen 'R' = 'r'
gemen 'S' = 's'
gemen 'T' = 't'
gemen 'U' = 'u'
gemen 'V' = 'v'
gemen 'W' = 'W'
gemen 'X' = 'x'
gemen 'Y' = 'y'
gemen 'Z' = 'z'
gemen _ = 'a'



dial = do 
print "Hello, what's your name?"
name <- getLine
print ("Hi there " ++ name ++ "!")
print "Where do you live?"
place <- getLine
print ("Oh really " ++ name ++ ", so do I!")
print ("Do you wanna switch to swedish?")
svar <- getLine
if svar == "yes" then print ("Kanon, da gor vi det!") else print ("English is just as good!")


perify :: [Char] -> [Char]
perify xs
    | (head (xs)) == 'P' = ", " ++ xs
    | (head (xs)) `notElem` kons = ", P" ++ [(gemen (head (xs)))] ++ (tail (xs))
    | otherwise = ", P" ++ (tail (xs))
```

Comment: What do you mean you need a code? Can't you just write the strings in Swedish?

Comment: Have you tried including them in the source code?

Comment: I've updated with my work so far. I must add, I'm an absolute NEWBIE at this. I want the conversation to be able to ask "do you want to switch to swedish" and the if yes, I want help in writing something that makes it possible with the swedish characters å ä ö. As of now, it writes for example å as \229.. Thank's for looking in to it!

Comment: You should use `putStrLn` instead of `print`. For details please read [GHC: Display of unicode characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365317/ghc-display-of-unicode-characters)

Comment: Thanks guys it works!!!

Comment: @Sfranss Did you accidentally create a second StackOverflow account?

Answer (score 8):

You're using `print` to print your strings. This will not only print non-ASCII characters (as well as non-printable characters and line breaks) using their escape codes, but also enclose the string in quotes.

For non-debugging purposes you should always use `putStrLn`, not `print` to print strings. This will not only not mess up the umlauts, but also get rid of the unwanted quotes and allow you to print newlines.

Comment: @Sfranss: Make sure to accept this answer if it solved your question (the little green mark below the downvote arrow on the left hand side).