# Does "putStrLn" support international characters?

Tags: haskell, io, internationalization

I've recently tried a function that converts some characters to greek characters to obscure text to software. However, the results are either printed out as "\###" or, in this case (putStrLn) not at all.

```
*Main> a
"H\949\921\921\959 \964h\949r\949!"
*Main> print a
"H\949\921\921\959 \964h\949r\949!"
*Main> putStrLn a
H*** Exception: <stdout>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)
*Main> :t a
a :: [Char]
*Main> putStrLn "Hello there!"
Hello there!
```

Comment: `let a = "H\949\921\921\959 \964h\949r\949!" in putStrLn a` works fine for me in several ghc versions. Not sure what the issue could be

Comment: I suspect this might be a platform issue... what operating system are you using? Haskell Platform or Stack? Which GHC?

Comment: Let me guess. Is this on windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GHC: Display of unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365317/ghc-display-of-unicode-characters)

Comment: Note that if you `print` a string, you will get non-ASCII chars escaped, and some ASCII quoted as well -- this is intentional. `putStrLn` should print the string as it is.

Comment: @chi Yes, it's Windows.

Comment: @jberryman No, It's not

Comment: On windows you need to 1) enable utf8 by running `chcp 65001` before you start `ghci`, and 2) use a console that actually has the Unicode fonts you need -- the default one likely does not. I used ConEmu with some success.